# Proving $v(s,p)=2^{p-1}(2s-1)$ is a bijection of natural numbers and $f(s)=2s-1$ is a bijection between natural numbers and odd numbers.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How do I prove this function is bijective?
$$
v(s,p)=2^{p-1}(2s-1).
$$
The domain is natural numbers and the codomain is also the natural numbers.

And this one:
$$
f(s)=2s-1.
$$
The domain is the natural numbers, and the codomain is the odd numbers in the natural numbers.

With this one I would do this to show it's injective:
$$
\begin{align}
v(s)&=v(s_1)\\
\implies 2s-1&=2s_1-1\\
\implies (2s_1)/2&=(2s_2)/2\\
\implies s=s_1
\end{align}
$$
So it's injective since if $v(s)=v(s_1)$ then $s=s_1$.

And to show it's surjective $f(s)=y$:
$$
\begin{align}
y&=2s-1\\
\implies s&=(y+1)/2
\end{align}
$$
Then the function must be surjective since every $y$ is the same as the codomain for $f$.

Am I correct?

Comment: It is impossible to know if your functions are bijective without knowing what their domains and codomains are. For example, your $f$ is a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but is not a bijection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "bijective" means "both injective and surjective".  "Injective" means "if f(x)= f(y) then x= y" and "surjective" means "for any y, there exist x such that f(x)= y".  With f(x)= 2x- 1 then if f(x)= f(y), 2x- 1= 2y- 1.  Adding 1 to both sides, 2x= 2y.  Dividing by 2, x= y.  To show that f is surjective, if y= 2x- 1, then 2x= y+ 1 and x= (y+ 1)/2.  Since that last, (y+ 1)/2, exists for all y, the function is surjective.

For $v(s, p)= 2^{p-1}(2s+  1)$,  to show "injective" we have to show that if $v(s_1,p_1)= v(s_2, p_2)$ then $s_1= s_2$ and $p_1= p_2$.    A crucial point is that $2^{p-1}$ is a power of 2 while 2s+1 is an odd number.  Use "unique prime factorization".

Comment: So the thing I did was correct, I suppose?

What do you mean by using "unique prime factorization?

Comment: And can I do it by arguing that every natural number can be written as a product of 2^k-1 and an odd number?