# Show function $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(m, n) = 2^{m}(2n + 1)$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \ \{0\}$ be the map given by $f(m, n) = 2^{m}(2n + 1)$ for all $(m, n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.  Show that $f$ is a bijection.

The above seems quite unintuitive since there needs to be a one to one correspondence. It has to be bijective but I don't know how I can prove that.

My thought process was that the first part of the function is always even and the second part $(2n+1)$ is even for odd $n$ and odd for even $n$.

This means that the result can be both even and odd. How do I show that there is no value that is hit twice?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than providing a link since links may get broken.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig oh okay my bad! should I watch the tutorial and then edit the question?

Comment: I edited this question.  However, you should read the tutorial so that you format your own questions properly in future.

Comment: Also, notice that $2n + 1$ is an odd number regardless of whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you very much! I'll read the tutorial for future posts.
Oh you're right I made a mistake there.
Since the first part is always even, and the second part always odd, shouldn't the result always be even?

Comment: Can $2^m(2n+1)$ equals $1$?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes if m = 0 and n = 0, right?

Comment: Well if $0\in \mathbb N$, then ask if $2^m (2n+1)$ equals $0$

Comment: Perhaps the question was intended to be a duplicate of [Proving $v(s,p)=2^{p-1}(2s-1)$ is a bijection$\dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3039432/318073). Then, positive integers can be factored uniquely into primes $p_1,p_2,p_3\dots$ and $p_1=2$ is the only even prime, $$N=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}\dots\space=2^{a_1}(p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}\dots)=2^{n-1}(2m-1),$$

where $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ are nonnegative integers and $n=a_1+1,m$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $f$ is not a bijection.

There are two cases to consider because different ideas what $\Bbb N$ is exist:

a) $0\in \Bbb N$. In that case, there is no $(m,n)$ with $f(m,n)=0$, because we always have $2^m\ne 0$ and $2n+1\ne0$.

b) $0\notin \Bbb N$. In that case,  there is no $(m,n)$ with $f(m,n)=1$, because we always have that $2^m\ge2$ and even, making $f(m,n)$ even.

In both cases, $f$ fails to be surjective, hence cannot be bijective.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I think there might be a problem in the question then since it clearly states that it should be bijective.

Comment: While this answers the letter of the question, I still think it is worthwhile to answer the spirit of the question, too; the function $g(m, n) = 2^m (2n + 1) - 1$ *is* a bijection in your first convention. (In particular, if we get to mix conventions, we can make $f$ a bijection.) In this case I would bet the question is a duplicate, though.

Comment: Yeah I edited the question (although poorly). It‘s now from Non-negative integers to positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

While Hagen's answer addresses the mistake in your question and why in that form it is not a bijection, this is a typical example of bijection if corrected. However, the form depends on whether you define natural numbers with $0$ or without. To avoid confusion, let's write $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ for non-negative and positive integers respectively.

For $f:\mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$, we can show that $f(m,n)=2^{m-1}(2n-1)$ is a bijection. The result follows from [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) (unique factorization theorem), since for every positive integer $a$ there exists (surjectivity) unique (injectivity) representation of $a$ in form $a=2^{e_1}(p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k})$ where $p_i$ is $i$-th prime number and $e_i \geq 0$. Then you can choose $m-1=e_1$ (since $e_1 \geq 0$ we have $m$ a positive integer) and $2n-1=p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ (since the primes on the right side are odd, their product is also odd and so $n$ is a positive integer).

For $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, we cannot invoke the unique factorization theorem directly because it does not apply for $0$, but we can use our previous result. If we shift $(m,n)$ to $(m+1,n+1)$ in $f$, we have a bijection $f':\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ given $f'(m,n)=2^{m}(2n+1)$. Now if we shift the resulting value by $-1$ we get a bijection $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ given $g(m,n)=2^{m}(2n+1)-1$.

To summarize, your original problem could be any of these bijections:

1. $f:\mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$, $f(m,n)=2^{m-1}(2n-1)$
2. $f':\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}, f'(m,n)=2^{m}(2n+1)$
3. $f'':\mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $f''(m,n)=2^{m-1}(2n-1)-1$ (not discussed above but an easy consequence)
4. $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $g(m,n)=2^{m}(2n+1)-1$

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the question (although poorly). It‘s now from Non-negative integers to positive integers.

Comment: @23408924 I would not advise editting after there have been answers (especially accepted). In that case you could either ask new question with proper statement, or perhaps include small note at the end of current question to clarify, but without modifying the original statement. Next, you did not modify the title. Also, what is $\mathbb{N} \ \{0\}$ ? That to me does not look like positive integers, maybe you meant something like $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ (`\setminus`).

Comment: yeah you're right. probably shouldn't change the question this way. Although actually someone already answered it for this it seems. Yeah I wanted to do the \setminus but I didn't know the right command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the image of the function, let $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\smallsetminus\{0\}$.

To show that $f$ is injective, suppose that $f(m,n)=f(r,s)$, that is
$$
2^m(2n+1)=2^r(2s+1).
$$
By the fundamental theorem of Arithmetic, you have unique factorisation, so that $m=r$, and so
$$
2n+1=2s+1
$$
which obviously implies that $n=s$. Therefore $(m,n)=(r,s)$ and $f$ is injective.

To prove that $f$ is surjective, if $a$ is a positive integer, let $m$ the highest power of 2 dividing $a$, then
$$
\frac{a}{2^m}
$$
is an odd integer, that you can write as $\frac{a}{2^m}=2^n+1$, for a unique integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So $f(m,n)=a$ and $f$ is surjective.